# ¿Como usar el OnPropertyChange en C#? [UWP]

Tags: c#, bucle-for, diccionarios

Lo que pasa es que tengo esta propiedad:

```
[Display(Name = "Codigo EAN-UCC", Description = "Codigo EAN-UCC para recaudos por codigo de barras", GroupName = "Tesoreria")]
public string TESORERIA_CODEANUCC { get { return (Get() == null ? "" : (string)Get()); } set { Set(value); OnPropertyChanged(); } }
```

Y pues esa propiedad la cargo con unos datos de una tabla llamada `Parametro` pero dentro de los requerimientos tengo que primero cargar un `Dictionary` que es este:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> Valores = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

y pues ya puedo cargar el `Dictionary` por medio de la consulta y un foreach sencillo:

```
foreach (var i in vr)
{
    Valores.Add(i.Codigo, i.Valor);
}
```

Y pues queda cargado el `Dictionary` asi que lo que tengo que hacer es a la propiedad asignarle su valor según la key del `Dictionary` y lo puedo hacer asi:

```
this.TESORERIA_CODEANUCC = Valores["TESORERIA_CODEANUCC"].ToString();
```

Y funciona perfecto, pero dentro de los requerimientos hay muchos parámetros y campos que llenar, podrían ser docenas, y pues tendría que declarar todos, ademas de que si se agrega una nueva en la base de datos, tendría que ir al código a agregarlo y pues la idea es que la programación sea escalable a futuro.

Asi que queria hacer algo con el `OnPropertyChange()`, quiero algo mas o menos que sea un bucle y en el foreach mientras agrega al `Dictionary` ir asignadole el valor a la propiedad. ¿Como podria hacerlo?

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que buscas hacer, buscas que el `OnPropertyChange` afecte a los cambios del `Dictionary` y de esa manera no definir la propiedad `TESORERIA_CODEANUCC`? o malinterprete la pregunta?

Comment: Quieres evitarte crear propiedades "a mano" para lo que te traes de la base de datos. Si estás usando INotifyPropertyChange, que intuyo que es así, no necesitas realmente crear las propiedades. Si editas y agregas la definición del método OnPropertyChange, y de esos Get y Set, podria agregar una respuesta.